# How to reduce flicker when scrolling & using jquery offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I've got the behavior I want: a target object that stays in the viewport when user scolls down the page (but always stays inside a parent container).  The problem is it flickers a lot when scrolling with the mouse.  Have a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/3ZQat/5/

**Markup:**

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='target'></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // variables
        var target = $('#target');
        var targetRect = target[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        var container = $('#container');
        var contRect = container[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

        // logic conditions
        var topOffScreen = false;
        var roomForTarget = false;

        // scroll event
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            targetRect = target[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            contRect = container[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            winTop = $(window).scrollTop();

            topOffScreen = (contRect.top < 0);
            roomForTarget = (contRect.bottom > target.height());

            // if container scrolls off top of viewport
            if(topOffScreen && roomForTarget){
                target.offset({top:winTop});
                target.css('border', 'solid 3px green');

            // if container fits in viewport entirely
            } else if (roomForTarget) {
                target.css('border', 'solid 3px green');
                // more code here

            // if container no longer fits in viewport
            } else {
                target.css('border', 'solid 3px red');
                // more code here
            }
        });

    });//end document.ready
})(jQuery);
```

How can I make this less jumpy?

Comment: Did you try not setting top to wintop in one step.. but make it gradual..?

Comment: @VirtualBaseClass Not yet.  Perhaps I could/should animate that (w/ jQuery? css transitions?), but it's slightly new territory for me.  Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: @doublejack.. You can check it here.. http://jsfiddle.net/nqZu2/2/

Might not be everything that you wanted.. but should give you some idea.

Comment: @doublejack.. had to add position absolute for the animation to work. I guess you can figure out the new coordinates for where you would want the box and fix that

Comment: @VirtualBaseClass.. Thanks, that is the direction I needed.  Speeding up the animation and using linear easing made it look pretty good.  This is my final version: http://jsfiddle.net/9gfPL/2/

Comment: Great job, glad to be of help :) Should I add mine as answer and you can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You can check it here.. jsfiddle.net/nqZu2/2 Might not be everything that you wanted.. but should give you some idea."

From the comments. Thanks